# I tried to integrate API, but result become null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to integrate Api jsonplaceholder but data still null, how to fix it? i got stuck tonight still now, what is mandatory to fetch api? i don't know how it's work

> class Model

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  User({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
  });

  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  factory User.fromRawJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        userId: json["albumId"],
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["thumbnailUrl"],
      );


}
```

> Api Service

```
import 'dart:developer';

import '../db/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Service {
  static const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1';
  Future<User> getApi() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return User.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Gagal fetch');
    }
  }
}
```

> this link api [Link](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

[image: Api Service]

[image: Screen View Result]

[image: Result]

Comment: Where are you calling the getApi() function?

Comment: must be calling function? so it is using futurebuilder or what?

Comment: Yes for that case you need to use futurebuilder. You can also call that function in initstate and when it fetches the data you can use setState() to refresh the widget tree. You can also add a button to do all!

Comment: still wrong sir, can u see my new post? at the answer column

Answer (score 2):

So using `setState`, you can have this

> main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'services/api_service.dart';
import 'db/user_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _service = Service();
  User? _user;

  @override
  initState() {
    _service.getApi().then((user) => setState(() => _user = user));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _user != null ? Text(_user!.body) : const Text('null'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or using `FutureBuilder`, you can have this

> main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'services/api_service.dart';
import 'db/user_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<User?>(
          future: Service().getApi(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: snapshot.data != null
                  ? Text(snapshot.data!.body)
                  : const Text('null'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

##### Update: Based on your comment for lists

> part of api_service.dart

```dart
class Service {
  static const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
  Future<List<User>> getApi() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      return data.map((d) => User.fromJson(d)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Gagal fetch');
    }
  }
}
```

Note that as we are expecting a list, specifying data `as List<dynamic>` is okay. If you try to be more specific by doing `as List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, it won't work. Like, dart will fetch the photos but just won't display them.

> part of main.dart

```dart
body: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
  future: Service().getApi(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data != null
        ? ListView.builder(itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            return Text(snapshot.data![index].body);
          }))
        : const Center(
            child: Text('null'),
          );
  },
)
```

Used ListView to show that the data where returned.

Comment: Woww!!!! Thanksss sir it's work i really happy with that bcause i got burn out after 8 hours stuck huhu, hm sir i got last question, how to create service when json like return list?

Comment: you are welcome. please mark it as the answer. so sorry for the burn outs. check out the answer again for the updates concerning lists. hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer with explanation 